# Center a SVG with div on hover of that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Basically,

I have a gradient bar and on hover of the USP's below the bar the gradient moves to above that USP with a triangle. Now I'm trying to figure out how I can get the center of an SVG to center inside of the USP on hover to make the gradient look like it has a triangle also. It's a little hard screenshot and codepen below.

http://codepen.io/nsmed/pen/MpOLpp?editors=1100

```
    <section class="small-business-split-header-block">
  <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="small-business-header">Your calls<br />answered brilliantly</h1>
      <p class="small-business-sub-header">Our small business services ensure you capture every opportunity and make your business look bigger. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sit amet semper ante. Ut vel odio.</p>
  </div><!--wrapper-->

    <div class="usp-bar">
        <p class="usp-one active">Telephone Answering</p>

        <span><img src="http://svgshare.com/i/y4.svg" /></span>
    </div><!--usp-bar-->
    </section>

    <div class="usp-list cf">
    <div class="usp active">
        <a href="#">
            <p>Need your own<br /><strong>dedicated PA?</strong></p>
        </a>
    </div><!--usp-->

    <div class="usp">
        <a href="#">
            <p>Looking for<br />an auto attendent?</p>
        </a>
    </div><!--usp-->


    <div class="usp">
        <a href="#">
            <p>Missing calls<br />on your mobile?</p>
        </a>
    </div><!--usp-->


    <div class="usp">
        <a href="#">
            <p>Looking for a<br />business number?</p>
        </a>
    </div><!--usp-->

</div><!--usp-list-->
```

[image]

Comment: To put it in other words you are trying to make the triangle match the gradient of the "Telephone Answering" div? So that they look like they are the same shape?

Comment: Yes that is a much better way of explaining it

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here try this, click on items to see the beak moving. It's not a production ready code, but you can take it from here :)

Markup

```
<div class="bar">

  <div class="bar-background">
    <div class="bar-slider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-items">Item 1</li>
  <li class="menu-items">Item 2</li>
  <li class="menu-items">Item 3</li>
  <li class="menu-items">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

SCSS

```
$bar-height: 6rem;
$bar-slider-height: 2rem;
$bar-slider-background: #ffffff;
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
}

.bar-background {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
      left, 
      rgba(0, 175, 169, 1) 30%, 
      rgba(1, 180, 172, 0.15) 60%);
  height: $bar-height;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar-slider {
  height: $bar-slider-height;
  margin-top: $bar-height - $bar-slider-height;
  display: flex;
  width: 200vw;
  transition: transform 1s linear;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100vw;
    display: block;
    background: $bar-slider-background;
    height: $bar-slider-height;
  }
  &:before {
    transform: skew(45deg) translateX(-50%);
  }
  &:after {
    transform: skew(-45deg)  translateX(-50%);
  }
}

.menu {
    height: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.menu-items {
  list-style: none;
}
```

JS

```
var slider = $('.bar-slider'),
  sliderCenter = parseInt(slider.width() / 4, 10); // taking 1/4 here because our slider is twice the width of viewPort

$('.menu-items').on('click', function() {
  var activeClassName = 'is-active';
  $(this)
    .addClass(activeClassName)
    .siblings()
    .removeClass(activeClassName);

  var activeItem = $('.' + activeClassName),
    activeItemPositonFromLeft = activeItem.position().left,
    activeItemCenter = parseInt(activeItem.width() / 2, 10),
    newPos = parseInt(activeItemPositonFromLeft - sliderCenter + activeItemCenter, 10),
    translateX = 'translateX(' + newPos + 'px)';
  slider.css({
    transform: translateX
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/robiosahan/pen/gmopRJ